# How to best represent rate or proportion as a feature?

Tags: machine-learning, preprocessing, feature-engineering

Given two features in a data set: `NFObs` (Number of failed observations) and `NObs` (Number of total observations), I'd like to better understand how I should represent these data for downstream use in binary classification problem using a decision tree model.

Should the features be left "as-is" **or** substituted for a new feature `FailRate` equivalent to `(NFObs / NObs)`?  My concern with the rate/proportion idea is that it the model will consider an instance originally `1/1` the same as an instance originally `500/500`.  However, someone interpreting the results of the model would value an instance with 500 observations much more than an instance with 1 observation.

`NFObs < NObs` and `NObs >= 1`

**Problem Description**

Each instance contains:

A unique id `uid`, representing some widget.

Two independent, quantitative measurements `feat1` and `feat2`.

`class` is `1` if an instance (observation) "failed" and `0` if the instance "passed".

`NFObs` is a count of how many times the `uid` has previously been reported `1`. (stored in some legacy db without access to `feat1` or `feat2`).

`NObs` is a count of how many times the `uid` has previously been reported either `1` or `0`.

Hypothesis is that a model can predict whether a widget will fail using historical fail rate and newly collected `feat1` and `feat2`

```
In [2]: df.head()
Out[2]: 

class   uid  feat1  feat2   NFObs   NObs
   1    001   63     21      500    500
   0    002   31     29        1      1
   1    003   38     56        1      1
   0    004   33     86        5     20
   0    005    7     35       13     77

In [3]: dfRate.head()
Out[3]:

class   uid  feat1  feat2   FailRate
   1    001   63     21       1.0
   0    002   31     29       1.0
   1    003   38     56       1.0
   0    004   33     86       0.25
   0    005    7     35       0.16
```

Any insight or suggested reading would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like Bayesian data analysis can help here quantifying the uncertainties. It will naturally take into account the number of observations, e.g. 500 observations make you more certain about some outcome rather than 1. Can you detail bit more the task and what questions you are trying to answer?

Comment: Tried to provide a more detailed description of the problem

Comment: I am not sure I understood the problem. But the model you have chosen, decision trees, is scale invariant. It does not matter if the feature is within [0, NObs] or [0, 1].